# How can I get a Class object, using the String containing the class's name?

Tags: java, class

I need to get a Class from its name, something like this:

```
public void getClass(String nameOfClass){
  Class<?> c = Class.forName(nameOfClass); // Doesn't work
  doSomethingWith(c);
}
```

But the code doesn't work. How can I get a class based on the name?

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you can tell us what exactly "doesn't" work like tell us what error you get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting class by its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119956/getting-class-by-its-name)

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass fully qualified name into `Class.forName(String name)` method.

Like this

`Class.forName("some.package.SomeClass");`

Comment: @kc2001 why do you need to get Class of the Class instance?

'static Class<?> forName(String className)'
From javadoc: Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.

Comment: @Ivan You're right.  I wasn't paying enough attention.  Let me finish this cup of coffee....