# How to parse String to an object

Tags: java, string, parsing, object

First of all, I've already searched around a bit, but couldn't really find an answer for my problem. If such a thread alreay exists, I'm sorry. Also, I'm only at a beginner's level, so maybe i just didn't understand what was being explained and maybe I don't use the right terminology.

I want to parse a String to an object type. For example:

```
Boat boat1 = new Motorboat();
String type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a type");
if(boat1 instanceof type)
{
    System.out.println("boat1 is a motorboat");
}
```

Boat is an abstract class and Motorboat is one of its subclasses.

I know this won't work, because type is a String, but how can i make this work? How can i parse this String to an object type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting class by its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119956/getting-class-by-its-name)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2408812/1114687).

Comment: Minor point:  You are (I believe) wanting to convert a string to a class, not an object of the class.  (A String already is an object.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lookup a Class object from a string with `Class.forName`:

```
String typeName = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a type");
Class<?> class = Class.forName(typeName);
if (class != null && class.isInstance(boat1))
{
    System.out.println("boat1 is a motorboat");
}
```

Pay special attention though because your comparison requires a *fully qualified classname* (that includes all packages).

Comment: That works so far, but now I want to parse boat1 to the type that the user has given. What I want is: 

    Motorboat boat2 = (type) boat1;

That still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3054461 Use [Class.cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1):

Try using the class of your object:

```
if (boat1.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(type)) {
    System.out.println("boat1 is a motorboat");
}
```