# How to check whether a class exists

Tags: java

Is there any static method of the 'Class' class that can tell us whether a user entered class (in the form of a String) is a valid existing Java class name or not?

Comment: I do not understand why you get down voted its a valid question by my opinion. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @HRgiger: Thank you, appreciate. :)

Comment: I can understand the downvote. a) The question is poorly worded. b) It is not well researched. c) see below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting class by its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119956/getting-class-by-its-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the existence of a class using [Class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) like this:

```
try 
{
   Class.forName( "myClassName" );
} 
catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) 
{

}
```

Comment: However, keep in mind that this actually loads the class, which may have side effects. Also, it can fail if the class itself exists, but can not load due to missing classes it relies on.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Class.forName` with a few extra parameters to get around the restrictions in Rahul's answer.

`Class.forName(String)` does indeed load and initialize the class, but `Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader)` does not initialize it if that second parameter is false.

If you have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
    static {
        System.out.println("foo loaded and initialized");
    }
}
```

and you have

```
Class.forName("com.example.Foo")
```

the output in the console will be `foo loaded and initialized`.

If you use

```
Class.forName("com.example.Foo", 
              false, 
              ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

you will see the static initializer is not called.