# How can I get the caller class object from a method in java?

Tags: java, class

I know I can get the method and classname from `StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();` but that is not what I want.
I want the class object, so I can access his interface, annotations, etc...

It is possible?
`Class<?> classObject = getCallerClass();`

I see this question, but that is just for the classname.

[How to get the caller class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306811/how-to-get-the-caller-class-in-java)

Edit: Now I'm passing the class this way:

`someService.dummyMethod(foo1, foo2, new Object(){}.getClass());`

```
  someService(String foo1, int foo2, Class<?> c) {
    // stuff here to get the methodname, 
    // the interface of the class and an annotation from the interface.
}
```

I call someService from a lot of different classes, If is not possible I will continue this way, but If there is a way to get the caller class at runtime I prefer that way.

Comment: the "class Object"? what exactly do you mean by that? Either way, why can't you get it from what you get out of the stackTrace?

Comment: I would strongly advice against doing such things. What you try to do here is a clear sign for a **bad architecture**. If a method needs a reference to its caller, it should demand it as **parameter** and the caller then should provide himself: `foo(this);`.

Comment: Note that a `Class<?>` object does only represent the class, not the instance. It sounds that you want to get the instance. So you would probably need something like a `Reference<?>`.

Comment: No, I want the class, not an instance.

Comment: I think you already have the classname at hand, don't you? You can retrieve the `Class` object, given the name. See [Getting class by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119956/getting-class-by-its-name).

Comment: Carefully read through the complete question you linked ([How to get the caller class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306811/how-to-get-the-caller-class-in-java)). Some of the answers show how to retrieve the `Class` object, not only the name.

Comment: Why are you now doing `new Object(){}.getClass()`? That's the class of an anonymous class of `Object`, not the class of your current instance. Use `this.getClass()` or `Foo.class`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the classname using the code of your linked question: [How to get the caller class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306811/how-to-get-the-caller-class-in-java)

Then use the classname to retrieve the class, using code from here: [Getting class by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119956/getting-class-by-its-name)

Complete code:

```
String callerName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();

try {
    Class<?> caller = Class.forName(callerName);
    // Do something with it ...
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*(community answer, since only mix of existing answers).*

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Java 9+ you can use [`java.lang.StackWalker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html).

```
public void foo() {
    Class<?> caller = StackWalker.getInstance(Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE)
            .getCallerClass();
}
```

However, since `StackWalker` is thread safe it might be beneficial to create an instance and store it somewhere (rather than create a new instance every time the method is called).

Javadoc of `getCallerClass()`:

> Gets the `Class` object of the caller who invoked the method that
>   invoked `getCallerClass`.
>
> This method filters reflection frames, `MethodHandle`, and hidden frames
>   regardless of the `SHOW_REFLECT_FRAMES` and `SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES` options
>   this `StackWalker` has been configured with.
>
> This method should be called when a caller frame is present. If it is
>   called from the bottom most frame on the stack, `IllegalCallerException`
>   will be thrown.
>
> This method throws `UnsupportedOperationException` if this `StackWalker`
>   is not configured with the `RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE` option.

Comment: Cool solution! But unfortunatelly I'm using java 8 but is good to know it

Comment: Exactly what I needed! (Super happy I finally got off of Java 8 lol)